# How to integrate delta function?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, complex-integration, dirac-delta

There is this question that ask me to compute

[image]

by performing a change of coordinates to polar coordinates.

My attempts:

I manage to change it to $$I=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} re^{-r}δ(r-R)d\theta\,dr$$ but the problem is how do I integrate delta function?

Comment: Hint: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a)$

Comment: hi @aleden thx for reply so for my integral is from 2pi to 0 for Re^(-R) d(theta) is it correct if I include the part where I use your method to integrate delta function?

Comment: Not quite, notice that the bounds of your integral are $[0,\infty]$ as opposed to those of the dirac functional equation, being $[-\infty,\infty]$. You would have to manipulate the equation in order make the bounds suitable to apply the above formula.

Comment: hi @aleden, So do I multiply 2 to my integral??? but my integrand is still                     Re^(-R) d(theta)??

Comment: You cannot just multiply by 2, since the integrand is not even. I would suggest utilizing the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), since it is $0$ for $r\lt 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$I~=~\int_{[0,2\pi]}\! d\theta \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \! dr~  re^{-r}~\delta (r-R) ~=~2\pi \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dr~H(r)  re^{-r}~\delta (r-R)~=~2\pi H(R)Re^{-R}, $$
where $H$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Comment: Evaluating between $[-\infty,\infty]$ would yield $0$ right?